# I'm trying to add a column value from another table in query

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to figure out where to add an additional variable to my query in order to pull it correctly, but I am having some issues. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT
tt.unit_id,
tt.latitude,
tt.longitude,
tt.gps_settings,
tt.timestamp
FROM AA55 tt
LEFT JOIN device_link AS dl ON dl.device_id = unit_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT unit_id, MAX(timestamp) AS MaxTimestamp FROM AA55 GROUP 
BY unit_id) AS groupedtt
ON tt.unit_id = groupedtt.unit_id
AND tt.timestamp = groupedtt. MaxTimestamp
WHERE dl.user_id = '$real_id';
```

Basically, I need to add a column called `nickname` from a table called `device_info`. I've tried adding the value right after `tt.unit_id`, but I keep getting an error saying

```
Unknown column 'unit_id' in 'on clause'
```

The nickname needs to be pulled by comparing `device_info.device_id` to `AA55.unit_id`.

Is there any way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: try changing "dl.device_id = unit_id" to "tt.unit_id = dl.device_id"  ( i changed the order because table tt is your base table). Using an alias requires to reference to that table by its alias.

Comment: I'm confused on what benefit that adds. When I run the query as it is, it works perfectly. For example, when I change it to say "SELECT tt.unit_id, aa.nickname ... FROM AA55 tt, device_info aa" is when the error occurs.

Comment: I misread your comment. if you join AA55 with device_info on             tt.unit_id = device_info.device_id it will work

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT
tt.unit_id,
d2.nickname,
tt.latitude,
tt.longitude,
tt.gps_settings,
tt.timestamp
FROM AA55 AS tt
LEFT JOIN device_link AS dl ON(tt.unit_id=dl.device_id)
LEFT JOIN device_info AS d2 ON(tt.unit_id=d2.device_id)
INNER JOIN (SELECT unit_id, MAX(timestamp) AS MaxTimestamp FROM AA55    
GROUP BY unit_id) AS groupedtt
ON(tt.unit_id = groupedtt.unit_id)
AND tt.timestamp = groupedtt. MaxTimestamp
WHERE dl.user_id = '$real_id';
```